# vb.net publish application with a database

Tags: database, vb.net, database-connection

i want to have a built in database for my project this is what i did so far, i placed the mdb file inside the project

C:\Users\Jedi Dioh\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\kuya jake\kuya jake\bin\Debug\

i did some research this is what i did

```
Public Module Module1

Public path As String = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase) + "\"


Public source As String = "Data Source = " + path.Replace("file:\", "") + "JIMMY.MDB"

End Module
```

now this is the form

```
    dbProvider = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;"
    dbSource = "Data Source = C:/JIMMY.mdb"

    con.ConnectionString = dbProvider & source


    'alternative way of connection
    'Dim fldr As String
    'Environment is the user profile
    'fldr = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) & "/AddressBook.mdb"
    'dbSource = "Data Source = " & fldr

    con.Open()


    sql = "select * from TURNING"
    da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con)
    da.Fill(ds, "RECORDS")


    con.Close()


    DataGridView1.DataSource = ds
    DataGridView1.DataMember = "RECORDS"
```

its fine when not published but when i run the published i get this error

[image]

i don't know what to do now

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices depending on whether you want changes that have been made to the database to preserved when you update the application or not.

If you do not care about the data in the database when you update the application, then you can include it in the project with a Build Action of Content and a Copy To Output Directory setting of Copy Always or Copy If Newer.

If you do care about the data in the database and don't want it to be overwritten when you update your application, then you need to store it in a well-known location (i.e. c:) and store the reference to that location in your application.